# 404 not found when run Vue app on node server with IIS

Tags: node.js, vue.js, iis

I've got a Vue app running on a node server and attempting to redirect the URL using IIS.  When the app runs on localhost with the port specified, it works fine:
[image]

However, when the redirect is attempted it finds index.html but it cannot find the CSS or JS files:
[image]
The expectation is that the page rendered by the redirect looks the same as the one rendered by `localhost:3001`.

Here is the redirect rule in IIS:
[image]

Here is a screenshot of the relevant folders:
[image]

Why isn't it finding the CSS and JS files for the redirect?

Comment: Can you show me your website basic settings? Usually localhost accesses the folder under wwwroot, What is the physical path of your website?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/httpplatformhandler/info Please use HttpPlatformHandler to forward the traffic, not your own URL rewrite rules.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was resolved by adding the following to the vue.config.js file -

```
publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? '/BusinessObjectsMetadata/' : '/'
```

Note - after adding this code, it was no longer possible to access `localhost:3001` on the server directly by typing that in the address bar.